# Ошибка вывода массива кнопок для Телеграм бота

Tags: php, массивы, telegram-bot

Написал вот такой не хитрый класс

```
class keyboard {

    private function inline_keyboard($button) {
        return [
            'inline_keyboard' => array($button)
        ];
    }

    private function keyboard($button) {
        return [
            'keyboard'        => array($button),
            'resize_keyboard' => true
        ];
    }

    public function buttons($options) {
        $array = [
            'authorize' => $this -> inline_keyboard(
                [[
                    'text' => 'Сайт',
                    'url'  => TOKEN_URL
                ]]
            ),
            'start_menu' => $this -> keyboard(
                [['text' => 'Кнопка 1'], ['text' => 'Кнопка 2']],
                [['text' => 'Кнопка 3']]
            )
        ];
        return $array[$options];
    }

}
```

что б вызывать клавиатуру таким способом например

```
$key = new \libraries\keyboard;
$botton = $key -> buttons('start_menu');
```

Распетатываю массив, там вот что

```
Array
(
    [keyboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Кнопка 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Кнопка 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [resize_keyboard] => 1
)
```

А массив для третей кнопки куда пропал? Ни как не пойму в чем проблема. Или я что то не вижу.

Переписал все, вот рабочий вариант, если кто то захочет использовать это же решение

```
class keyboard {

    private function inline_keyboard($button) {
        return [
            'inline_keyboard' => $button
        ];
    }

    private function keyboard($button) {
        return [
            'keyboard'        => $button,
            'resize_keyboard' => true
        ];
    }

    public function buttons($options) {
        $array = [
            'authorize' => $this -> inline_keyboard(
                [
                    [[
                        'text' => 'Перейти на сайт',
                        'url'  => 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'
                    ]]
                ]
            ),
            'start_menu' => $this -> keyboard(
                [
                    [['text' => 'Кнопка 1'], ['text' => 'Кнопка 2']],
                    [['text' => 'Кнопка 3']]
                ]
            )
        ];
        return $array[$options];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется должно быть так

```
[['text' => 'Кнопка 1'], ['text' => 'Кнопка 2'],['text' => 'Кнопка 3']]
```

а у вас

```
[['text' => 'Кнопка 1'], ['text' => 'Кнопка 2']], [['text' => 'Кнопка 3']]
```

то есть рано закрыли квадратную скобку после  `'Кнопка 2'` и еще одну открыли перед `'text' => 'Кнопка 3'`

Comment: В таком виде принимает Телеграм кнопки, массив массивов, там все верно, просто должен быть ниже еще один массив, но его нет почему то. В таком виде если записать кнопки будут в 2 строки, я этот код всегда использовал, когда на прямую использовал, а сегодня решил в класс вставить и вот такая незадача.

Comment: @Денис нет. посмотрите внимательней. у вас не массив массивов. у вас там синтаксическая ошибка. Странно, что вам не выбивает -- syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: @Денис вот сравните ваш вариант http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c34ac9648d61e613a6ee6758cb2076316e301e1  и рабочий  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18f9f3ec70406ab69c314a76e0933a54526ed6e9

Comment: в том и дело что ошибок нет, и даже в бота приходят кнопки, только почему то 2, в одну строку а должны били прийти 3 в 2 строки, 2 сверху и 1 снизу. Ошибки не будет, выше есть функции, там массив объявлен же, эти массивы внутри другого массива лежат

Comment: @Денис ну доказывать больше я ничего не буду. Для меня тут всё очевидно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, перепишу тогда функцию, вынесу туда массив сразу.

Comment: @Денис `[['text' => 'Кнопка 1'], ['text' => 'Кнопка 2']]` - видите слева открывающую скобку а справа закрывающую? Это вы открыли массив массивов и закрыли. Всё. дальше `, [['text' => 'Кнопка 3']]` идёт в небытие.

Comment: уже понял, еще раз спасибо.